# Understanding PHP Class OOP structure

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to create a class function but somehow it won’t work and I can’t figure out what’s the problem. Is it the way I declare the variable or what so ever?

```
<?php 

class Car{

var $model;
var $make;
var $speed;

function Car ( $model, $make, $speed)
{
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->make = $make;
    $this->speed = $speed;
}

function accelerate ($speed)
{
    $add = 5;
    $speed = $speed + $add;
    return $speed;
}

function get_status()
{
    echo "Car status :   \n";
    echo "Model      :"  $this-> model "\n";
    echo "Make       :"  $this-> make  "\n\n";
}

function get_speed()
{
    return $this->speed;
}
}
?>

<?php
$car1 = new Car();

$car1 -> get_status("Vios", "Toyota");
for( $i = 0; $i < 5 ; $i++)
{
    echo "Accelerating... <br> \n";
    echo "Current speed : accelerate(5) km/h <br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: is there any problem at all or.. ?

Comment: Make sure you declare public, private, or protected on all properties, like you have var, and on all functions. Also, please show the execution of your class->method()s.

Comment: You are using php4 style. You are calling a method `get_status` with arguments that are not defined. When accelerating you are updating a local variable instead of the object member. You are not actually calling accelerate anywhere. So which of of these is the problem you are having? As @philipp tells you you are not concatenating strings correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of issues with your code. But at least this cleaned up version should work without the script dying completely. Here is a breakdown of what I did:

- Set the variables that were set as `var` to `public` since that is the preferred method of setting variables.
- In `function Car`, I set default values for `$model`, `$make` & `$speed` so if they are not passed—like in your example—there is at least a default value to act on.
- Your `echo` lines in `get_status` did not have the `.` for concatenation so they were not properly concatenating the strings.
- Then you setting `$this-> make` and `$this-> model` with empty spaces is syntactically incorrect. So set those to `$this->make` and `$this->model`.
- Then when you are calling the class, you set this `"Current speed : accelerate(5) km/h <br>";` which is syntactically incorrect as well. So set that to `echo "Current speed : " . $car1->accelerate(5) . " km/h <br>";` so it can actually echo values.

But that said, unclear on what the output is for this code. The logic is a bit of a mess. But at least it’s not completely dying like it did before!

And here is the cleaned up code:

```
class Car {

  public $model;
  public $make;
  public $speed;

  function Car ($model = 0, $make = 0, $speed = 0) {
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->make = $make;
    $this->speed = $speed;
  }

  function accelerate ($speed) {
    $add = 5;
    $speed = $speed + $add;
    return $speed;
  }

  function get_status () {
    echo "Car status :   \n";
    echo "Model      :" . $this->model . "\n";
    echo "Make       :" . $this->make  . "\n\n";
  }

  function get_speed () {
    return $this->speed;
  }

}

$car1 = new Car();
$car1->get_status("Vios", "Toyota");

for( $i = 0; $i < 5 ; $i++) {
    echo "Accelerating... <br> \n";
    echo "Current speed : " . $car1->accelerate(5) . " km/h <br>";
}
```

And—like I said before—since the way you are calling the class makes little sense to the structure you have, I slightly reworked the code above so it loops through an array of car values like this:

```
$car_array = array("Vios", "Toyota");

foreach ($car_array as $car_value) {
  $car1 = new Car($car_value);
  $car1->get_status();

  for( $i = 0; $i < 5 ; $i++) {
    echo "Accelerating... <br> \n";
    echo "Current speed : " . $car1->accelerate(5) . " km/h <br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for pointing it out... The logic is that it should display

The car accelerates with the increment of 5 each time the loop runs..

Answer (score 0):

When concatenating strings, you must use the dot operator:

```
echo "abcd" . "efgh";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor like this:

```
public function __construct($model = 0, $make = 0, $speed = 0) {
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->make = $make;
    $this->speed = $speed;
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php